# Netbeans and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans

I recently installed netbeans 6.9.1
Use it with Ruby Rails 3.0.1, when creating the project, standard catalog "app", "config", "db" turned into "Controllers", "Helpers" and others.
Screenshot::
http://pics.kz/s1/2c/ce/da/2cceda36066160b03fd9c37733b12585.png

How to make the directories were in standard form?

Comment: You can fix that by not using NetBeans. It offers nothing more than plain Vim + Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

That's the project view. Look for the 'file' view (Window menu, Files, or Ctrl-2) to switch to the file view.

What I like about the project view is that it allows you to navigate to your ruby library directories with your gems. Much easier to find and read your library code than it is with vim or textmate.